# Riemann-Stieltjes Integral Exercise

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

The truth is that I have no experience with the integral of Riemann-Stieltjes and developing a Bayesian inference problem in the book *Mathematical Statistics* by Shao, appears one of these steps, I do not understand completely.

Could you guide me on this?

\begin{align}
\delta(x) & =\frac{1}{p(x)}\int \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\theta\exp\left\{-\frac{n}{2}\frac{(x-\theta)^2}{\sigma^2}\right\}\pi(\theta)d\nu \\ 
& = x+\frac{1}{p(x)}\int \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}(\theta-x)\exp\left\{-\frac{n}{2}\frac{(x-\theta)^2}{\sigma^2}\right\}\pi(\theta)d\nu
\end{align}

Note that $\pi(\theta)$ is a prior density with respect to a $\sigma$-finite measure $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: is $\nu$ absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure?  then we would just need another density and we could integrate regularly. In any case, as it stands, it doesn't look like this has any "Stieltjes" to it, since Stieltjes measure of the distribution has already been accounted for with the density

Comment: What do you mean another density? That is precisely what complicates me. If we assume that $ \nu $ is a probability measure, say $ d \nu = dF (\theta) $ is it the same as saying $ dF (\theta) = \pi (\theta) $? in which case the product would have a $ \pi (\theta) \pi (\theta) d \theta $?

Comment: You can't integrate this if you don't know what $\nu$ is; if $\nu$ is just some abstract measure, without any explicit formula for the distribution function at least, this is closed form. There is no reason to assume that $\pi(\theta)$ and $\nu$ are in any way related.

Comment: If $\nu$ is not Lebesgue measure, and you have no information about what specifically $\nu$ is, there is no way you can reduce this expression further. $\nu$ and $\pi$ can't be related in the sense of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral, $\int \pi(\theta) d \theta = \int dF(\theta)$ - note that unless $\nu$ is Lebesgue measure (i.e. "$d\theta$") then it does not come into the picture at all here, $F$ here is meant to denote the distribution function corresponding to the distribution which has density $\pi$

Comment: Yes, you are right. $\nu$ is lebesgue measure, hence the problem is trivial. I got confused with the notation. You've helped me understand the concept a little better.

Comment: I hope I wasn't unnecessarily short with you - but anyway I'm glad I could help. I didn't find Riemann-Stieltjes integration straightforward at first either.